# What's the difference between two usages of <pre> tag?

Tags: php, html, output, echo, pre

Consider below code :

```
<?php
function a($txt) {
    b("Cleveland");
}
function b($txt) {
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}
echo '<pre>';
a("Peter");
'</pre>';
?>
```

Output :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(40) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\hello.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(6)
    ["function"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["args"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Cleveland"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(40) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\hello.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(12)
    ["function"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["args"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Peter"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, consider below code :

```
<?php
function a($txt) {
    b("Cleveland");
}
function b($txt) {
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}
echo '<pre>'.a("Peter").'</pre>';
?>
```

Output :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(40) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\hello.php" ["line"]=> int(3) ["function"]=> string(1) "b" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Cleveland" } } [1]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(40) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\hello.php" ["line"]=> int(8) ["function"]=> string(1) "a" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Peter" } } }
```

Why I'm getting two different outputs for the two different usages of `<pre>` tag?

```
echo '<pre>';
a("Peter");
'</pre>';
```

AND

```
echo '<pre>'.a("Peter").'</pre>';
```

I think I'm doing nothing different in both of the statements. I'm doing almost the same thing then why I'm getting different outputs?

Comment: `'</pre>';` does **exactly** nothing. You can put instead `'</bla>';` or just `'bla';`, it's the same. It is a string lost in the PHP code, an expression without any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` outputs to STDOUT. `var_dump` outputs to `STDOUT`.

> ```
> echo '<pre>';
> a("Peter");
> '</pre>';
> ```

This **outputs** `<pre>`.

Then it **outputs** the var_dump.

Then it waves the string literal `</pre>` around in the air doing nothing with it.

---

> ```
> echo '<pre>'.a("Peter").'</pre>';
> ```

This starts building a string.

It starts with `<pre>`.

Then it **outputs** the result of `var_dump`, and joins **the return value** of the `a` function (which doesn't have a `return` statement) to the string.

Then it joins `</pre>` to the string.

**Finally** it **outputs** the string (`<pre></pre>`)

Comment: Excellent explanation of the effects of the `'</pre>';` statement :-)

Answer (score 2):

`echo` only runs once it's finished building the string. So if you run

```
function a() {
  echo 'A';
}
echo 'Hello ' . a();
```

you'll end up with the output

> AHello

This is because the function is evaluated as part of building up the output to the echo call. If the function itself has an `echo` statement (or `var_dump`, `print_r`, etc), then it will be shown first.

There are two options to resolve this:

**1) Refactor your function to *return* the string instead**

```
function a() {
  return 'A';
}
echo 'Hello ' . a();
```

**2) Call your function as part of a separate echo call, using commas instead of string concatenation:**

```
function a() {
  echo 'A';
}
echo 'Hello ' , a();
```

In both of these cases you'll end up with the correct output:

> Hello A

Specifically for your question, the output you're seeing is the output from `var_dump`, followed by `<pre></pre>`, which won't show up at all. (Or actually, as many people have mentioned now, just `<pre>`. Although this won't have been making much difference to the behaviour.)